# Is it incorrect to use the phrase "X percent probability?"

Tags: probability, popular-math

Very frequently, phrases like "50 percent probability" are used in science papers and popular writing. Is this phrase generally viewed to be correct by the mathematical community. Formally a probability is a number between 0 and 1, but the percent usage is so ubiquitous I'm wondering if such a colloquial usage is considered to be a problem.

Comment: There is a one to one correspondence between the % language and the mathematical language. So it does not matters which way you talk about probabilities. However using the mathematical language makes everything easier. Laymen, however, like the % language better. Why? Perhaps the % sign is know from grade school.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's not a problem at all, and in fact, the word "percent", which is usually shorthanded by the symbol %, literally means /100, i.e., in words divided-by-one-hundred.
And in this context, saying "50 percent probability" is equivalent to saying "0.50 probability".

Answer (score 2):

One problem with using percentages is that they can be used both as fractions and as measures of change, leading to confusion.

For example, if the probability of event A is $40\%$ and the probability of event B is $25\%$ higher than the probability of event A, then is the probability of event B $50\% = 40\% +25\% \times 40\%$, or is it $65\% = 40\% + 25\%$?